# How to display a list of the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Please tell me how to get a list of all existing SQL Server database instances into a listbox , so that the user can select their database. Thank you!

Comment: Please can you add what you have tried so far. People are happy to help answer questions and help out if a problem occurs, but generally don't like doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the sys.databases table for that probably;

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: and how display to listbox?

Comment: To limit the list to databases the user can access, `SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;`.

Comment: in what, c#? sql? visual-studio? you've used all of these tags. you could do a quick google search on the language you're using (hint: sql-server has this built into SSMS)

Comment: in C#. I'm not find in google.

Comment: You can't have looked hard. This is my very first search; https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=creating%20a%20listbox%20c%23 The first result is literally a tutorial on listboxes in c#